# How to loop through all filter options in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'd like to use a loop to go through each of the criteria in a filter, then calculate and output averages. My code below calculates the averages and outputs them on the next empty line of the second sheet, but unfortunately, this only works for the first filter selection. After each new iteration of the loop, nothing happens. Can anyone help?

[source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2A9i.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wNqj.png)

```
    Option Explicit

Sub avg()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim nextrow As Long


Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
RowCount = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Set rng1 = ws1.Range("G2:G" & lastrow)

   For Each cell In rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        With ws1.AutoFilter.Range
        ws2.Range("A" & RowCount + 1) = ws1.Range("B" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value2
        ws2.Range("B" & RowCount + 1) = ws1.Range("F" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value2
        End With

            ws2.Range("C" & RowCount + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws1.Range("Y2:Y" & lastrow & ",Z2:Z" & lastrow & ",AA2:AA" & lastrow _
            & ",AD2:AD" & lastrow & ",AE2:AE" & lastrow & ",AI2:AI" & lastrow & ",AK2:AK" & lastrow & ",AL2:AL" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

            ws2.Range("D" & RowCount + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws1.Range("AF2:AF" & lastrow & ",AM2:AM" & lastrow & ",AP2:AP" & lastrow _
            & ",AQ2:AQ" & lastrow & ",AR2:AR" & lastrow & ",AS2:AS" & lastrow & ",AT2:AT" & lastrow & ",AU2:AU" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

            ws2.Range("E" & RowCount + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws1.Range("AW2:AW" & lastrow & ",AX2:AX" & lastrow & ",AY2:AY" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

 Next cell

 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. If you need average for each criteria, can you use Pivot instead?

Comment: @NareshBhople no, the averages are across columns

Comment: @NareshBhople I did just try it to make sure, and it doesn't seem to be possible in pivot

Comment: To better understand, I would suggest you submit a sample data or screen shot of excel with column, row numbers and sheet names.

Comment: @NareshBhople links to images added in post above. the second image shows that the code works for the first SiteDate, but the next iterations of the loops do nothing

Comment: So, on the the next row in output you need averages for HS020 Date 11/07/2019?

Comment: yes, exactly, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few changes made in your macro. Note the newly added array for unique values of filter criteria and loop changed from each cells to array. `lastrow` and `RowCount` variables replaced by `lastrow1` and `lastrow2`.

```
Sub avg()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range, rng1 As Range, rng1Crt As Range
Dim lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, arr As Variant

Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
lastrow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = ws1.Range("G1:G" & lastrow1)

rng1.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
Set rng1Crt = rng1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'Populating array with filter criteria values
ReDim arr(0 To rng1Crt.Cells.Count - 1)
i = 0
For Each cell In rng1Crt.Cells
arr(i) = cell.Value
i = i + 1
Next

ws1.ShowAllData
rng1.AutoFilter

For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    lastrow2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    rng1.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr(i)

    With ws1.AutoFilter.Range
    ws2.Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1) = ws1.Range("B" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value2
    ws2.Range("B" & lastrow2 + 1) = ws1.Range("F" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value2
    End With

    ws2.Range("C" & lastrow2 + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws1.Range("Y2:Y" & lastrow1 & ",Z2:Z" & lastrow1 & ",AA2:AA" & lastrow1 _
    & ",AD2:AD" & lastrow1 & ",AE2:AE" & lastrow1 & ",AI2:AI" & lastrow1 & ",AK2:AK" & lastrow1 & ",AL2:AL" & lastrow1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

    ws2.Range("D" & lastrow2 + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws1.Range("AF2:AF" & lastrow1 & ",AM2:AM" & lastrow1 & ",AP2:AP" & lastrow1 _
    & ",AQ2:AQ" & lastrow1 & ",AR2:AR" & lastrow1 & ",AS2:AS" & lastrow1 & ",AT2:AT" & lastrow1 & ",AU2:AU" & lastrow1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

    ws2.Range("E" & lastrow2 + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws1.Range("AW2:AW" & lastrow1 & ",AX2:AX" & lastrow1 & ",AY2:AY" & lastrow1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks so much for this -- it's looking much better. I think the array is what I was missing. However, for me it's only outputting the first filter selection (JVLWCA) for 47 rows. Not sure why this would be?

Comment: Answer edited .. added line `rng1.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=arr(i)` in the loop .. Set rng1 changed to G1

Comment: thanks for this, hopefully last question... now this is giving me a different selection (the last in the array), but still repeating for all the rows

Comment: yes, instead of JVLWCA, now it gives me CAM139. also I was getting 'Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error' so I changed to `field:=1` instead of 7 since rng1 is only column G, hope that makes sense

Comment: Ohh!! Yes the sutofilter range is only column G .. The code is working fine for me. try debugging for sample rows say (15 or 20 rows) with step into (key F8)

Comment: great! so now do you know how can I get it to output all filter selections rather than just one? EDIT: never mind, typo on my end! all solved. thank you so much for all your help!!!

Comment: Glad to hear that  :). Welcome.